# in which thread message will be process when using HandlerThread?

Tags: android, handler

below code written in UI thread

```
Handler handler

 HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("SquareHandlerThread");
        thread.start(); // starts the thread.
        Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
```

//below code written in UI thread and take the looper of HandlerThread

```
        handler = new Handler(looper)
       {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
           // do something
         }
      };
```

//some other thread i used i can access reference of the handler which created above

```
hadler.sendMessage(messageObject)
```

now the question is in which thread messages will be processed ,inside mainthread or separate thread which created by HandlerThread(it gives looper to handler)?

Comment: excersise: Log.d in handleMessage() the value of  Thread.currentThread()

Comment: @ pskink : thank you for your comment..I am new to android , I have excercised as you said it shows that message processed in HandlerThread. but my doubt is handler is created in ui thread but using looper of HandlerThread....What the android docs says is handler always associated with thread where is it created...it leads me to post this question here why message processed in HandlerThread instead of main thread...because handler associated with ui thread only right?

Comment: its because you created the Handler using HandlerThread'd Looper

Comment: @pskink thank you for your reply..if i understood correctly means..handler always associated with thread where it is created but if we create handler using  Looper of Handlerthread(but inside oncreate() method of acitvity ie.ui thread),handlemessage will be processed in HandlerThread not in ui thread eventhough if it is created in ui thread with HandlerThread Looper